# Multiple App Executed Bluemix

Tags: node.js, heroku, ibm-cloud, procfile

Can I run multiple apps/processes in one Bluemix instance? Right now I run them on localhost with one on port 3000 and the other on 4000. The second app is in a subfolder of the parent app, but they do not share any dependencies. I can split them up, that's no problem, but I want to know how to get them to run at the same time when I push to Bluemix. Do I create a procfile with web: node app.js and then web: node enterprise/app.js on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to run these apps as two different Bluemix applications. You can not customize the open ports on a Bluemix application, so your current setup would not be possible. If you want to deploy them in the same command, I would suggest setting up a deployment pipeline that takes each app from their respective place in the source code directory and deploys them to two separate endpoints.